# JAXBElement<Boolean> vs boolean

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, boolean

What exactly is `JAXBElement Boolean` and how can I set this to the boolean equivalent of "`true`"?

Method:

```
  public void setIncludeAllSubaccounts(JAXBElement<Boolean> paramJAXBElement)
  {
    this.includeAllSubaccounts = paramJAXBElement;
  }
```

This does **not** compile:

```
returnMessageFilter.setIncludeAllSubaccounts(true);
```

Comment: If the method expects a [`JAXBElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html), why are you trying to pass `true`, a boolean?

Comment: Can you include the code where you are having problem and the stacktrace?

Comment: Create a JAXBElement, eg: `JAXBElement<Boolean> jaxtrue = new JaxBElement(qname, Boolean.TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);` and pass that

Comment: Alright, I've kind of figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `JAXBElement` is generated as part of your model when a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation would not be able to tell what to do based on the value alone.  In your example you probably had an element like:

```xml
<xsd:element 
    name="includeAllSubaccounts" type="xsd:boolean" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The generated property can't be `boolean` because `boolean` doesn't represent `null`.  You could make the property `Boolean` but then how do you distinguish been a missing element and an element set with `xsi:nil`.  This is where JAXBElement comes in.  See below for a full example:

**Foo**

```
package forum12713373;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlElementRef(name="absent")
    JAXBElement<Boolean> absent;

    @XmlElementRef(name="setToNull")
    JAXBElement<Boolean> setToNull;

    @XmlElementRef(name="setToValue")
    JAXBElement<Boolean> setToValue;

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

```
package forum12713373;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="absent")
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createAbsent(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement(new QName("absent"), Boolean.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="setToNull")
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createSetToNull(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement(new QName("setToNull"), Boolean.class, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name="setToValue")
    public JAXBElement<Boolean> createSetToValue(Boolean value) {
        return new JAXBElement(new QName("setToValue"), Boolean.class, value);
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum12713373;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.absent = null;
        foo.setToNull = objectFactory.createSetToNull(null);
        foo.setToValue = objectFactory.createSetToValue(false);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <setToNull xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <setToValue>false</setToValue>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to NullUserException's comment, I was able implement this in one line. It is slightly different so I thought I'd post it for the benefit of others.

```
returnMessageFilter.setIncludeAllSubaccounts(new JAXBElement<Boolean>(new QName("IncludeAllSubaccounts"), 
Boolean.TYPE, Boolean.TRUE));
```

Just to clarify, the QName is the XmlElement tag name.

Also, needed to import:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
```

**Edit**

Better to use the convenience method in `ObjectFactory` class that returns the `JAXBElement` as Blaise suggested.

Comment: FYI - As part of your generated model there should be an `ObjectFactory` class that contains a convenience method to create the necessary `JAXBElement` with the appropriate `QName`.

Comment: Oh yes, there is. It didn't seem right that I needed to create one from out of the blue. Thank you!